# AJAX I must double click to submit second textarea! (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //Do not submit the form
        var dataflow=$(this).serialize(); //Get the inputs value
        $.post('{{route('homepage.update')}}', dataflow, function (data){ //post.create is the route name
            //The request is done, do something with the server response
        });
    });
});
```

I use this to save form without refresh

Here is my route

```
Route::post('/homepage/update', 'AdminController@Update')->name('homepage.update');
```

And my html

```
        {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title"><b class="fa fa-pencil"></b> Title</label>
        <input id="title" class="form-control" value="{{ $article->title }}" name="title">
        <br />
        <label for="content"><b class="fa fa-home"></b> Desc</label>
      <div class="box-body pad">
            <textarea id="content" name="content" rows="10" cols="80">
                 {{ $article->content }}
            </textarea>
     </div>
      </div>
      <center>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><b class="fa fa-save"></b> Submit</button>
      </form>
```

My function who update ajax data

```
    public function HomePage(Request $r) {
    $article = Article::find(1);

    $article->title = $r->input('title');
    $article->content = $r->input('content');
    $article->homepage = 1;

    $article->save();

}
```

The problem is i must click twice button to save two forms when i click one it submit only title! Please help how to fix that

Comment: When you click submit, in the network tab of developer tools, do you see both values of form being submitted?

Comment: I see only success i specify when all is done only one and when i click twice twice show it!

Comment: Whenever you submit a form, check the network tab. You should see the request being made and values being sent in the request body. What are those values? From what I can tell, form is being submitted fine. Probably some issue on the backend

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ia2j1t here is on first click
here is second http://prntscr.com/ia2jcc

Comment: Ignore error above its from my editor